# Angular JS Controller Function not being stepped into

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to simply throw some JSON data onto a page from a GET call.

This is my HTML (**Please be aware this is loaded into index.html which has the correct angular notation)**:

```
<h1>Downloads</h1>
<div class="container" ng-controller="DownloadCtrl as download">
  <p>{{download.routes}}</p>
</div>
```

This is the download controller:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('dashboardApp').controller('DownloadCtrl', DownloadCtrl);
  DownloadCtrl.$inject= ['DownloadService'];

  function DownloadCtrl(DownloadService){
    var self = this;
    self.routes = function(){
      DownloadService.getRoutes()
        .then(function(responseData) {
          self.routes = responseData;           
      });
    };
  };
})();
```

This is the download service:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('dashboardApp')
    .factory('DownloadService', DownloadService);

  DownloadService.$inject = ['$http', '$sessionStorage'];

  var baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/Dashboard/rest/download/';

  function DownloadService ($http, $sessionStorage){
    var service = {};
    service.getRoutes = getRoutes;
    return service;

    function getRoutes(){
      return $http.get(baseURL+"route",$sessionStorage.sessionData.sessionID);
    }
  }
})();
```

I have debugged the application and it does hit **self.routes** however it just skips over it and no data is displayed.

I also am not receiving any errors in the console. It just skips over the function.

This is my first AngularJS application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is bad organized, 
the error resides in the view, because it is not calling the method `self.routes`, it is just printing out...

your view must do something like that:

```
<p>{{download.routes()}}</p>
```

But, this is a bad way to code...
Please, consider doing something like that:

```js
DownloadService
  .getRoutes()
  .then(function(responseData){
    self.routes = responseData;         
  })
;

// instead of

self.routes = function(){

  DownloadService.getRoutes()
  .then(function(responseData){
    self.routes = responseData;         
  });

};
```

Comment: Yes I have just noticed that I am assigning it twice and that is very stupid.

Comment: 1 Vote up for pointing out my mistakes but even assigning the DownloadService to a getRoutes call doesn't fix the problem. I think there is more to the issue.

Comment: This answer resolves the question, but community member to community member: the tone is not constructive. I would generally avoid statements like "This is a bad way to code..." in answers. Show the alternatives and let the facts stand for themselves. Maybe link a style guide for further reading.

Comment: Yeah, you are together right, i'm afraid but I wouldn't to be offensive, it depends on my english that isn't good... Sincerely, I'm sorry about that tone...

Comment: It has fixed the problem. I implemented your answer wrong. I am not offended. Thank you very much.